# What language can create relatively quick starting cross-platform applications with custom widgets?

Tags: user-interface, programming-languages, cross-platform

I want to create an application that "plays well as a tray icon". That is, it starts up quick and doesn't hog resources. The application will likely need some custom UI widgets as well, and although I mention "tray icon", cross-platform would be ideal as well.

Obviously, I can do this with C++ and some cross-platform UI library (I wouldn't know which one), but I was hoping for a language with garbage collection.

I can do this with Java, but I'm guessing even after compilation, it likely builds a relatively large and slow-starting .exe (maybe the SWT UI library would cut some bloat?). Another way to ask this question, is it possible in Java, and if so what is the best way to make quick/snappy app? I want it pop up similar as popping up Google Desktop search.

Is there something "between Java and C++?"

So,
* Higher-level than C++ (mainly GC)
* Quick starting and resource friendly/snappy (.exe or otherwise) 
* Cross-platform desktop UI (even with custom UI widgets)

Comment: You don't need a tray icon app to start fast since it runs all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`Python`](http://www.python.org) it is a high level  cross-platform language with GC.

Comment: +1 add wxWidgets or Qt to Python and you will tick all the boxes

Answer (score 1):

Use **Qt** and pick an arbitrary supported language

Here is the link to it : [Qt - A cross-platform application and UI framework](http://qt.nokia.com/)
You can use it freely if you don't develop commercial application.

The reference documentation is very good, and you can find a lot of help all over the net.
It uses a hierarchy of the objects, and if a parent object destroys, it frees up all the children. In a GUI app you don't have to bother with deallocations, if you use the proper syntax.  I am developing a 2D presentation application for linux with it, and I am very satisfied with its performance.

Don't forget to use Qt Creator if you decide to use Qt, it simplifies project creation, contains "intellisense", very useful. Without it Qt is a pain..

Supported programming languages: (quoted from qt site)

> **Programming Language Support**
>
> The Qt API is implemented in **C++**, and
>   provides additional features for
>   easier cross-platform development. **QML**
>   – introduced with Qt 4.7 – QML is a
>   JavaScript-based declarative, language
>   designed to describe the user
>   interface of a program: both what it
>   looks like, and how it behaves.
>   Bindings to Qt exist for several other
>   languages, including **Ada, Pascal,
>   Perl, PHP, Ruby, Python and Java™**.

Comment: its C++, or you want to learn a new language ? You can also try .NET 2.0 with Mono on other platforms, its mostly implemented, but you will get smaller performance.

Comment: @ch0kee the question asked "higher level than C++" and wanted garbage collection

Comment: @David Heffernan : the question was "What language can create ...?". He asked also a method for Java to do the work. As I saw, he knows both C++ and Java, but didn't find a solution. He also mentioned he didn't find a proper cross-platform UI library for C++.

Comment: @ch0kee do you see the bit of the Q where he rules out C++ and requests something higher level and with GC? Paragraphs 2 and 5.

Comment: @David Heffernan QT provides a "higher level" of abstraction, and provides some kind of memory management, deletes QObject objects.   Paragraph 2 didn't rule out C++. Look at this sentences from his question : "Another way to ask this question, is it possible in Java, and if so what is the best way to make quick/snappy app?" and this "Is there something "between Java and C++?"". So he ruled out java ?

Comment: @ch0kee I would want to spin up a Java (or .net) VM for a tray app. I loath C++ (that's clearly a personal opinion) and find it too low level. There are intermediates. For small projects I find Python hits the sweet spot, for me.

Comment: I meant I would not want to spin up a java vm for this

Comment: @David Heffernan Anyway, Qt was a common point. I don't like interpreted languages because of their known disadvantages. I agree that c++ is a bit verbose, but I wouldn't stigmatize it low level, don't forget the boost libraries, and c++ is all about paying only for what you use, there are a lot of extension for it (also garbage collection libraries), but you don't download it with the language, like with Java, you can get later what you need. P.S. I'm using bash for small projects ;) Thanks for your comments. Yes, gc is a good thing. In the next c++ standard it will be implemented we hope.

Comment: @David Heffernan I've edited my post and inserted the list of supported languages, so now I think its okay.  And what about Mono ? I have used it long ago.